# Get-LocalUser doesn't work with Microsoft Account as documented

Tags: windows-10, powershell, user-accounts

According to the article [Get-LocalUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localuser?view=powershell-5.1), the syntax to get a Microsoft local account from PowerShell is:

```
Get-LocalUser -Name "MicrosoftAccount\myemail@outlook.com"
```

Except when I run this, I get the following error:

> Get-LocalUser : User MicrosoftAccount\myemail@outlook.com was not found.

However, the account is definitely there. What am I missing here?

[image]

Later... I removed the account manually and then ran the following:

```
New-LocalUser -Name "MicrosoftAccount\myemail@outlook.com" -Description "Local account"
```

And then got this error message:

> New-LocalUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The character length of the 48 argument is too long.
>   Shorten the character length of the argument so it is fewer than or equal to "20" characters, and then try the command
>   again.

The actual email I'm using is reasonably long as it's of the form firstname.lastname-company@outlook.com - I wonder if there is an very old character limit in there somewhere from when local accounts were limited in length?

Comment: To restrict `Get-LocalUser` output to `MicrosoftAccount`s use `Get-LocalUser | Where-Object PrincipalSource -eq 'MicrosoftAccount'` The name for that Account here doesn't contain the email though.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this one off quickly - it's a limitation of the *LocalUser cmdlets which are limited to 20 characters. This article flags it as a documentation bug...

[New-localuser cmdlet fails length check on Name parameter](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3045)